# NoMethodError in CollectionsController#create undefined method `file' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, paperclip, docsplit

I'm trying to upload a pdf file to dropbox through rails and convert the pages in the pdf into jpeg images and store those images in the same dropbox folder.
 I tried using Docsplit gem but i dont know how to address the file inthe drop box in code.

**Docsplit.extract_images(@collection.file.url, :format => [:jpeg])**

file.url shoul return the file right? 
or any other ways??

thanks,

Comment: `@collection` is nil.  Hence the error.

Comment: You should inspect why `@collection` is nil. The message means that you can't call the method `file` on a nil object, because the method is not defined for it.